# How to report a bug (16.04 freezing, peristently)

Tags: 16.04, freeze, bug-reporting, yoga-2

my Ubuntu 16.04.2 (on my yoga 2 11) installation keeps freezing, causing me to have to force reboot. This is a persistent issue, and is not caused by any proprietary kernel software being in use. I'm not sure how to look at the logs to see what is causing it, or how to report the bug if it's a bug I'm experiencing, but some guidance would be greatly appreciated. 
If it helps, I always have my laptop plugged into my tv? (which is how i know the system is freezing copletely- the panel clock stops counting the seconds when it freezes)

Comment: If you  switch from tty7 to tty1 and back does the session become unfrozen?

Comment: Idk I'll let you know next time it freezes

Comment: *"I'm not sure how to look at the logs to see what is causing it"* - Please post the output of  running`cat /var/log/syslog` in the terminal right after a freeze at http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: It JUST froze, all I did was reboot and do as you said

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24377905/

Comment: Oh, i forgot to switch from TTY7 this time

Comment: it froze this time, and didn't wtich from tty7 to anything, it was a kernel freeze in pretty sure. want my log?

Comment: idk if this is any help, but it goes right back to when my computer froze

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24402321/